# Intel Tbb overhead issue

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, intel, tbb, overhead

Im using Intel TBB to parallel processing some parts of an algorithm processed on images. Although the processing for each pixel is data dependent, there are some cases which 2 consecutive pixels could be processed in parallel as below.

```
ProcessImage(image)
    for each row in image // Create and wait root task for each line here using allocate_root()
        ProcessRow(row) 
        for each 2 pixel
            if(parallel())
                ProcessPixel(A) and ProcessPixel(B) in parallel // For testing, create and process 2 tbb::empty_task() here as child tasks
            else
                ProcessPixel(A)
                ProcessPixel(B)
```

However, the overhead occurs because this processing is very fast. For each input  image (size of 512x512), the processing costs about 5-6 ms.
When I experimentally used Intel TBB as comment block above, the processing costs more than 25 ms.

So is there any better way using Intel TBB without overhead issue or other more efficient way to improve performance of simple and fast processing program like this ?

Comment: If it's so fast, why do you care how fast it is? If the answer is "because I need to process a lot of images", then parallelize at the image level (or maybe even many-image level), not the pixel level.

Comment: @T.C No, I need to improve on single image only. I'm just curious about the possibility of Intel TBB in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

TBB does not add such a big (~20ms) overheads for invocation of a parallel algorithm. My guess (since there is no specifics provided) is that it is related to one of the following:

1. If you measure only the first invocation, it includes overheads for worker threads creation. And note, TBB does not have barriers like OpenMP, so one call to `parallel_for` might not be enough to create all the threads)
2. Same situation happens after worker threads go to sleep because of absence of the parallel work for them. The overheads for the wakeup are orders of magnitude lower than for the threads creation but still can affect measurements and impose wrong conclusions.
3. TBB scheduler can steal a task from outer level to the nested level (blocking call) thus the measurements will look like it takes too long for processing the nested part only while it is busy with an extra work there.
4. There is a contention for processing (A) and (B) in parallel caused by either explicit (e.g. mutex) or implicit (e.g. false sharing) reasons. But anyway, it is not TBB-specific.

Thus, the advice for performance measurements with TBB is to consider only the total time for long enough sequence of computations that will hide initialization overheads.

And of course as was advised, parallel first on the outer level. TBB provides enough different patterns for that including `tbb::parallel_pipeline` and `tbb::flow::graph`